# statusBarStyle not changing?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uikit

The gist of this question is pretty straightforward. I'm trying to set the statusBarStyle of my UIApplication to UIStatusBarStyleLightContent in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (pictured below) but for some reason the value isn't sticking.

```
 NSLog(@"%ld",[[UIApplication sharedApplication]statusBarStyle]); //logs 0
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
 NSLog(@"%ld",[[UIApplication sharedApplication]statusBarStyle]); //logs 0
```

My only guess as to the problem is that it might have something to do with my usage of UIPageViewController, set as the root view controller in this case.

```
[self.window setRootViewController:self.pageViewController];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to go to the .plist file of your project, and add/set the key:

"View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO.

Comment: Sharp. I didn't realize it defaulted to YES.

Comment: This problem appeared in Xcode 5/iOS 7, even if you want the status bar to be hidden all the times, now it is not enough to only check the "Hide during application launch" option.

Answer (score 2):

try setting set the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to NO in the plist.

Then in your viewController..

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    }
}
```